# Finding details when German killed in action during World War 2

Tags: germany, military-records, world-war-2

Thaddeous Zak(Zack)
10. Komp fliger Aushbiloting(?) Regiment 72
Feld post Number 47671
10 Komp Jager Regiment 22 (Luftwaffe)

'' OPERATION WALDTEUFEL''. From the 6th to 23rd March 1945, the 11th Luftwaffe Division crossed the Drava River near Valpovo and advanced towards Bolman and Tarjanci.

They were pushed back by a counter attack from the 3rd Ukranian Front. His family never heard from him again.

Comment: Contact the Bundesarchiv for details as mentioned above. There often is only sparse information for soldiers who died in the last months of the war, as records were lost or never created.

Comment: "Komp" is an abbreviation for Kompagnie (company). "fliger Aushbiloting(?) Regiment 72" probably should read: Flieger Ausbildungs Regiment 72 (Flight Training Regiment 72). The "Feldpost Nummer" is a military post office address.